# Kazuma quad 110cc 4 stroke won’t start

Tags: starting

I bought above quad as none runner. Compression is 75psi I’m sure I read this is too low to start. I added a small amount of oil through spark plug hole and compression increased to 105psi. My understanding is this points to piston, rings or barrel. I’ve removed barrel and piston from quad, on the bench I reinserted the piston into barrel and added fuel on top of piston. I was expecting to see the fuel pass by the rings and leak out to the other side of the barrel. None of the fuel leaked past. Could it still be rings, piston or barrel?

---

I don’t have the manual. 
I Changed the barrel, piston and rings tonight.  It’s now 90psi and +15 increase.  It could still be low unsure.  Will see if starts tomorrow. Valve clearance set to 0.07 and 0.12.

Comment: Did you check the valves?

Comment: Yes the valves are set correct. I checked them and they were already set correct.

Comment: Do you know what the compression should be?

Comment: No, did you check the manual? Have you got the manual?

Comment: 100psi may be a lower limit, a quick google search gives : https://www.pitbikeclub.co.uk/showthread.php?t=42414

Comment: Tried to start Just now still nothing. Any suggestions what to check next plz. Spark there. Unsure what to do next.

Comment: Check the valves for sealing. Just went through the same issue and the intake valve was leaking a bit.